# Excel macro to populate a column with conditions from other column

Tags: vba, excel

I am a beginner in VBA. I have an Excel tracker as below:

```
S.NO    REGION  ASSOCIATE   DATE RECEIVED   SLA TIME BUY    DELIVERED DATE  STATUS
1   ME           7-Mar-13                 ED    10-Mar-13             
2   ME           7-Mar-13                    10-Mar-13    
3   AFRICA           7-Mar-13                    9-Mar-13   
4   AFRICA           7-Mar-13                 AE    12-Mar-13   
5   ASIA             8-Mar-13                    11-Mar-13  
6   ASIA             9-Mar-13                 QR    15-Mar-13   
7   AFRICA           10-Mar-13                   14-Mar-13
8   ASIA             10-Mar-13                   16-Mar-13  
9   ME           10-Mar-13                   14-Mar-13  
10  ASIA             10-Mar-13                DH    17-Mar-13
```

I have to populate dates in the SLZ column based on the values of Region Column Date Received and Time buy column.The conditions are given below.

**Conditions**:

1. If the region is ME ,the ticket is received on 7th and this has to be delivered on 9th march, however as ED is marked in column F I get one more day extra to complete my work and now if I deliver this on 10th my status msg should show WSLA.
2. IF the ticket is received on 7th and this had to be delivered on 9th and no data in column F hence if the delivery date is after 9th march I shoul get a msg O SLA.
3. If the region is africa the ticket is received on 7th and this has to be delivered on 9th and no data marked in column f; since SLA and delivery matches the comment has to be W SLA.
   If this case is received on 7th which should on 9th however as the column say AE one more day is still considered as SLA; but still the delived day is 12th march which is two days delay my column H must say OSLA
4. This is an Asia I case; I have 4 days time to deliver this; however I have delived one day b4 my solumn H must say W SLA

Finally my report should look like this.

```
S.NO    REGION  ASSOCIATE   DATE RECEIVED   SLA TIME BUY    DELIVERED DATE  STATUS
1   ME      7-Mar-13    9-Mar-13              ED    10-Mar-13   W SLA
2   ME      7-Mar-13    9-Mar-13                 10-Mar-13           O SLA
3   AFRICA      7-Mar-13    9-Mar-13                 9-Mar-13            W SLA
4   AFRICA      7-Mar-13    10-Mar-13             AE    12-Mar-13            O SLA
5   ASIA        8-Mar-13    11-Mar-13                11-Mar-13           W SLA
6   ASIA        9-Mar-13    14-Mar-13             QR    15-Mar-13       O SLA
7   AFRICA      10-Mar-13   14-Mar-13                14-Mar-13           W SLA
8   ASIA        10-Mar-13   16-Mar-13                16-Mar-13           W SLA
9   ME      10-Mar-13   14-Mar-13                14-Mar-13           W SLA
10  ASIA        10-Mar-13   17-Mar-13             DH    17-Mar-13   W SLA
```

Can somebody please help me with a macro. If I get a macro for at least one condition check, I think I can recreate it for other conditions.

Comment: So, what have you tried? Any code? Any error messages?

Comment: you don't need a VBA macro to do that, you could put your conditions in formulas in the columns for example **=IF(REGION="ME,RESULT,NO_RESULT)**

Comment: What 'SLZ' column, I can only see SLA

Answer (score 0):

so you want something along the lines of:

```
dim iCol as integer
dim iRow as integer
dim iRegionCol as integer, iTktReceivedDate as integer
'
'
iRegionCol=2 ' column 2 = column B?
iTktReceivedDate=4 ' column 4 = column D?
'
for iRow=2 to range("A1").end(xldown).row
    select case cells(irow,iregioncol).text
        case "ME"
        ' do something like IF cells(irow, iTktReceivedDate) = today() then...
        case "Africa"
        ' do Africa something
        case "Asia"
        ' do something for Asia
    end select
next
```

I hope that gets you started

Philip